# ルートドメインでサイトが表示されないドメインがある

Tags: nginx

サブドメインで表示しているサイトを、ルートドメインで表示するよう変更しようとしているのですがうまくいきません

---

**ルートドメインが正常表示されているドメイン(〇〇〇〇.co.jp)**
/etc/nginx/conf.d/〇〇〇〇.co.jp.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  〇〇〇〇.co.jp;
    root   /var/www/html/〇〇〇〇.co.jp/〇〇〇〇.co.jp/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
```

---

**ルートドメインが正常表示されないドメイン(xxxx.co.jp)**
/etc/nginx/conf.d/xxxx.co.jp.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxxx.co.jp;
    root   /var/www/html/xxxx.co.jp/xxxx.co.jp/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
```

ブラウザ(Microsoft Edge)の画面表示

> Web アドレスが正しいことを確認してください:

---

**試したこと**
/etc/nginx/conf.d/xxxx.co.jp.confを下記へ変更後、Nginx再起動

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxxx.co.jp;
    root   /var/www/html/〇〇〇〇.co.jp/〇〇〇〇.co.jp/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
```

ブラウザ(Microsoft Edge)の画面表示

> Web アドレスが正しいことを確認してください:

**補足**
・xxxx.co.jpのサブドメイン(hoge.xxxx.co.jp)は正常表示されています

**質問**
・ドメインはそれぞれ異なる「ドメイン公式登録サービス」から取得していますが、関係ありますか？
・原因として考えられることは？

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx

---

**2020/3/24追記**

[nslookup(dig)テスト【DNSサーバ接続確認】](https://www.cman.jp/network/support/nslookup.html)を試してみました。
nslookup結果

> Non-authoritative answer:
>   *** Can't find xxxx.co.jp: No answer

dig結果

> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: xxxx.co.jp.     300 IN  SOA 01.dnsv.jp.
>   hostmaster.dnsv.jp. 1563788518 3600 900 604800 300

〇〇〇〇.co.jpとは異なり、この後「ADDITIONAL SECTION」が表示されていないのですが、関係ありますか？

Comment: 「Web アドレスが正しいことを確認してください:」という表示が出た際に使ったURLは、どのような内容だったのですか？

Comment: wwwなしの「xxxx.co.jp」でアクセスした際、「Web アドレスが正しいことを確認してください:」と表示されました

Comment: そもそもDNSのAレコードにルートドメインが登録されていますか？不明な場合は、nslookupやdig等で確認してみてください。

Comment: nslookupとdig(意味は良く分かっていません)を試した結果を、本文へ追加しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ドメインからIPの名前解決がされていないようなので、
Webサーバの設定の問題ではなくて、DNSの設定の問題のようです。
おそらくルートドメインの設定がされていないか間違った設定をされているように見受けられます。

ご利用になられているDNSサービスをご確認してください。
ドメインレジストラにオプションとしてDNSサービスを利用していたり、もしくはAWSRoute53のようにPaasで提供されていたり、もしくは自前のネームサーバを用意したりしているので、どのような設定をしたらよいのか、どのように修正すればよいのかは違ってきます。

ちなみに、レジストラやDNSやネームサーバなどはWebエンジニアであればかなり大事な知識の一つだと思っています一度目を通しておいたほうが良いと思います。digやnslookupなどはドメイン⇔IPを扱うコマンドです。
https://www.nadukete.net/domain-guide/setting/server.html

Comment: DNS設定を誤っていました。www.xxxx.co.jpが表示されたので、サーバ側の問題だと思っていました。www.xxxx.co.jp(サブドメイン？) と xxxx.co.jpは、サーバ側で設定変更するものだと思っていました